# Getting data out of Profile2 with field_get_items()

Tags: users

I am trying to access my profile2 fields in template.php. I get profiledata, but I also get an error message:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing type profile2. in entity_extract_ids() (row 7663 of /includes/common.inc).

Should not the entity type in `field_get_items()` be `'profile2'`, or is it another value?

```
$profiledata = profile2_load_by_user($variables['comment']->uid);
$lastname = field_get_items('profile2', $profiledata, 'field_lastname');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`profile2_load_by_user()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_by_user/7) takes a user account (not just a uid) as its first argument, so you'll need to use:

```
$account = user_load($variables['comment']->uid);
$profiledata = profile2_load_by_user($account);
$lastname = field_get_items('profile2',$profiledata,'field_lastname');
```

Answer (score 5):

As @Clive mentioned `profile2_load_by_user()` takes user account object not uid, but you also need type name as second argument to retrieve `field_lastname` using `field_get_items` function.

I recommend you to use this function [`profile2_by_uid_load`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!contrib!profile2_page.module/function/profile2_by_uid_load/7) instead of `profile2_load_by_user`

So your code should look like the following:

```
$profiledata = profile2_by_uid_load($variables['comment']->uid, 'profile_type_name');

$lastname = '';

if($profiledata) {

  $lastname  = field_get_items('profile2', $profiledata, 'field_lastname');
}
```

Comment: The returned value is an array. So you should add "$lastname = $lastname[0]['safe_value'];" before the last line.